# Don't let flex to wrap label text of toggle

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have the following code (with `"@fluentui/react": "^8.33.0",`)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Toggle } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Toggle';

class TestIt extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
        <Toggle onText="Width Limit Auto" offText="Width Limit Manual"/>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
export default TestIt;
```

It has the following result where the label text is wrapped. If I remove `display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'`, the label text is not wrapped.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't want to wrap the label text; I don't understand why `display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'` (for some reason / other code, I need to keep it) has an effect on that.

For instance, there is no problem with codepen: https://codepen.io/SoftTimur/pen/JjJaRvv.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is `width` of `parent element`. First you have unnecessary wrapper over `Toggle Component` because it covers only one element inside `flex`:

[image]

Here you are few [Codepen examples](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/xxrQJaK?editors=0010).

**Note:**

**Codepen** has dynamic `width` and that's the reason why text wrap doesn't exist. But it shows up when you have overflow or fixed width. Put at your local example some CSS for `body` and `html` or at parent element:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```